# prebuilt binutils that run on android device

Tags: android-ndk, arm, binutils

I can not find any built versions of the binutils that could be pushed to an Android device an then be executed from there. The Android NDK toolchain provides them but in the wrong format.

Devices need them in ELF 32bit executable for ARM , but the toolchain only provides :

```
compiledtoolchain/bin$ file arm-linux-androideabi-objdump 
arm-linux-androideabi-objdump: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
```

Does anyone know if and where to find objdump in a format so that it can be executed directly on an ARM android device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it on an Android device, but you might want to look at the pre-built binaries of my ELLCC cross compiler project: ftp://ellcc.org/pub (http://ellcc.org). Each tarball contains binaries for the clang/LLVM based C/C++ compiler, pre-built libraries, gdb, and the GNU binutils. All of the executables are statically linked so they don't rely on any shared libraries being available on the target system.

Comment: Great, that's good to know. I suspected it would since the system calls should be the same as other Linux systems, but haven't had the chance to try it.